# Datagridview Column Index Returning 0 after Update

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I Bind Data to a DataGridview using the following code

```
private void BindGrid()
        {
            try
            {
                string constr = "Data Source=INSPIRE-1;" +
             "Initial Catalog=testdatabase;" +
             "User id=testuser;" +
             "Password=tester;";
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM mytable", con))
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                        {
                            using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                            {
                                sda.Fill(dt);
                                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (flag == false)
                {
                    flag = true;
                    DataGridViewButtonColumn uninstallButtonColumn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
                    uninstallButtonColumn.Name = "Edit";
                    uninstallButtonColumn.Text = "Edit";
                    dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(4, uninstallButtonColumn);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
            }
        }
```

I Update the selected record by hooking to a button click event in the datagridview row like this

```
void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex ==4)
            {
                button4.Enabled = false;

                try
                {
                    orderId = (string)dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].OwningRow.Cells[0].Value;
                    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constr))
                    {

                        try
                        {
                            conn.Open();
                            SqlDataReader myReader = null;
                            string commandText = "select * from mytable where name= @name";
                            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, conn);
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", orderId);
                            myReader = command.ExecuteReader();
                            while (myReader.Read())
                            {
                                textBox1.Text = myReader["name"].ToString();
                                textBox2.Text = myReader["age"].ToString();
                                textBox3.Text = myReader["phone"].ToString();
                                textBox4.Text = myReader["address"].ToString();


                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception err)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
                        }

                    }
                }
                catch (Exception error)
                {
                }

            }

        }
```

Now i update the values using the code below

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd =
                new SqlCommand("UPDATE mytable SET name=@NewName,age=@NewAge,phone=@NewPhone,Address=@NewAddress" +
                    " WHERE name=@oldname", conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewName", textBox1.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewAge", textBox2.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewPhone", textBox3.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewAddress", textBox4.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oldname", orderId);
                try
                {
                    int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("Updated Successfully");
                }
                catch (SqlException ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
        BindGrid();
        textBox1.Clear();
        textBox2.Clear();
        textBox3.Clear();
        textBox4.Clear();
        button4.Enabled=true;


    }
```

But after i click the Update Button then click on the Button Column corresponding to a Row `e.ColumnIndex` always returns 0.

What im i doing wrong?

UPDATE :

Please see the screenshot

[image]

Comment: what is the place/position of `Button` in your `DataGridView`?

Comment: @RahulHendawe Its in the first code snippet `dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(4, uninstallButtonColumn);`.Please check.

Comment: Sorry didn't notice it, check below answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rahul's Answer will work but looks like `orderId = (string)dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].OwningRow.Cells[0].Value;` should be modifiled to get `Cells[1].Value` and not 0 as 0 is the button cell from 2nd time onwards. But for 1st time you need to use 0 as then button is at index 4. Try below changes.

As far as I understand, issue is after update, you call the BindGrid again and since flag is true it just sets the datasource again for the grid and not generating button again thus button gets moved to index 0 followed by the datatable columns.

Another way to solve is modify your code a bit like 
`dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(0, uninstallButtonColumn);`
`dataGridView1.Columns[0].DisplayIndex = 4;`

And then in `CellClick` event check for `e.ColumnIndex == 0`. This help you in showing the button at the position you want and always the click work as the columnindex never changes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But the button still remains there in the 4th column after clicking the `Update` button.

Comment: Yes. But what exactly is required? It should be moved? Does not the if condition of Update Click satisfy?

Comment: The button should stay there and when i click on it the textboxes should be updated with the values in the row. It works as intended before clicking the update button,but after clicking the update button.Clicking on the row button cell does not produce values in the textbox.

Comment: Please see the updated question with the screenshot.

Comment: Yes the reason I see is mentioned above. `orderId = (string)dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].OwningRow.Cells[0].Value;' should be changed to `orderId = (string)dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].OwningRow.Cells[1].Value;' with the other changes I have mentioned.

Comment: Changes are `dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(0, uninstallButtonColumn);`                    `dataGridView1.Columns[0].DisplayIndex = 4;` `orderId = (string)dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].OwningRow.Cells[1].Value;` and `if (e.ColumnIndex ==0)` at the relevant lines in your code shared above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116644/discussion-between-nishitha-nair-and-techno).

Comment: The same issue occurred again.Could you please take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38300744/datagridview-button-click-event-not-firing

Answer (score 0):

you can check `button index` like below without comparing its `index`:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    var senderGrid = (DataGridView)sender;

    if (senderGrid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewButtonColumn &&
        e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        //TODO - Button Clicked - Execute Code Here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but Still the same issue.The code works before clicking the update button but after i click the update button ,nothing works..

Comment: put breakpoint on `BindGrid()`method and check whether lines inside `if (flag == false)` is executing or not, I suspect next time when you click on `update_button` as you set  `flag==true`  lines inside `if (flag == false)` are not executing.

Comment: After update button is clicked the code for adding the button is not executed.I added a flag to prevent duplicate button entry in the datagrid.

Comment: So, does the Button still remain there with same name and index? Sorry I don't have enough Ideas about this that's why asking. I guess you can check with regenerating the `button` by executing that much lines.

Comment: No Problem :) Thanks for your help.The button remains there.I tried clearing the Gridview and removing the flag.. does not work